# Get double as a result of division of integer values

Tags: c++

If a person has low income (<= 25,000) and the consulting time is less than or equal to 30 minutes, there are no charges; otherwise, the service charges are 40% of the regular hourly rate for the time over 30 minutes.

For others, if the consulting time is less than or equal to 20 minutes, there are no service charges; otherwise, service charges are 70% of the regular hourly rate for the time over 20 minutes.

(For example, suppose that a person has low income and spent 1 hour and 15 minutes, and the hourly rate is $70.00. Then the billing amount is 70.00 * 0.40 * (45 / 60) = $21.00.)

Write a program in C++ that prompts the user to enter the hourly rate, the total consulting time, and whether the person has low income. The program should output the billing amount.

**This is what I have done so far and the program looks correct to me, but for some reason I do not get the correct output. I get 0.00 which is a wrong output value.**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double calculateBill(int income, int consultingMinutes, double hourlyRate);

int main()
{
    int income; 
    double consultingMinutes;
    double hourlyRate;

    cout << "Please enter the clients income: $" ;
    cin >> income; 

    cout << "Please enter the consulting time in minutes: ";
    cin >> consultingMinutes;

    cout << "Please enter the hourly rate: $";
    cin >> hourlyRate; cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    cout << "Your total bill ammount comes to: $" << calculateBill(income, consultingMinutes, hourlyRate) << endl;

    return 0;
}

double calculateBill(int income, int consultingMinutes, double hourlyRate)
{
    if (income <= 25000) { 
        if (consultingMinutes <= 30) 
            return 0; 
    else 
        return hourlyRate * 0.40 * ((consultingMinutes - 30) / 60);
    }
    else { 
        if (consultingMinutes <= 20) 
            return 0;
        else 
            return hourlyRate * 0.70 * ((consultingMinutes - 20) / 60);
    }
}
```

Comment: Review how integer division works in C++.

Comment: @jwimberley just realized that. It is the data type of the variable consultingMinutes that is causing the error. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing of integers and floats is not a very good thing. Try this:

```
return hourlyRate * 0.40 * (((double) consultingMinutes - 30.0) / 60.0);
```

instead of this:

```
return hourlyRate * 0.40 * ((consultingMinutes - 30) / 60);
```

(And apply the same fix for the second wrong place `return hourlyRate * 0.70 * ((consultingMinutes - 20) / 60);`)